# Trying to create a stored procedure that will build multiple entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We use a product that essentially sets permissions for objects via a SQL table. I am trying to create a stored procedure that will essentially set the permissions for one user to the same as another. Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SETPRODUCTS
    @sourceCC BIGINT,
    @targetCC BIGINT
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL varchar(5000)

    DECLARE @Sequence_Id varchar(50)
    SET @sequence_id = 0

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DELETE FROM TCC WHERE CC_Id = @targetCC

    DECLARE cursorCurrent CURSOR FOR
        SELECT MAX(TCC_Id) + 1 
        FROM TCC WITH (tablockx holdlock)

    OPEN cursorCurrent
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorCurrent INTO @sequence_id

    IF (@sequence_id IS NULL) 
       SET @sequence_id = 1

    INSERT INTO TCC (TCC_Id, T_Id, CCC_Id) 
    VALUES (@sequence_id,
        (SELECT T_Id FROM TCC WHERE CC_Id = @sourceCC), @targetCC)

    CLOSE cursorCurrent
    DEALLOCATE cursorCurrent

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

The error I get is that my subquery has more than one value, which is true. I want to take every entry from that subquery and use it to insert new rows into my database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you creating a cursor and then only using the first row??? And be very careful here with your TCC_Id. Using MAX + 1 is prone to a LOT of error. Even using tablockx holdlock you can still get some errors. I would prefer to use an identity here as it already handles all of the concurrency issues that are so challenging to do yourself.

Comment: How would I go about using an identity?

Comment: You would have a column in TCC that is an identity column. Then this entire process becomes a single insert statement with no extra code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Comment: My only concern is regarding adding additional columns to this database. I don't see any triggers on this particular table, but could anything (say, upgrades to the application) create issues going forward if I add an identity column? I assume I would need to retroactively populate for the previously existing rows in the table?

Comment: I couldn't possibly tell you that adding a new column will not cause an issue. I am guessing this is a third party application? If you add an identity column to an existing database it will populate the existing rows.

Comment: Fair enough - and you are right, it's a 3rd party app. Their solution to this is to manually add each product to the user individually. 300 users x 100 products is a LOT of clicking. Just looking for ways to simplify things for my team. Thanks for the info though! Maybe it will help with the full solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this version of Insert:

```
INSERT INTO TCC (TCC_Id, T_Id, CCC_Id)
   SELECT @sequence_id, @targetCC, T_Id FROM TCC WHERE CC_Id = @sourceCC
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter your procedure as below

```
Alter PROCEDURE SETPRODUCTS
@sourceCC BIGINT,
@targetCC BIGINT
 BEGIN
 DECLARE @SQL varchar(5000)

DECLARE @Sequence_Id varchar(50)
SET @sequence_id = 0

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE FROM TCC WHERE CC_Id = @targetCC

DECLARE cursorCurrent CURSOR FOR
    SELECT MAX(TCC_Id) + 1 
    FROM TCC WITH (tablockx holdlock)

OPEN cursorCurrent
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorCurrent INTO @sequence_id
Declare @total int
IF (@sequence_id IS NULL) 
   SET @sequence_id = 1

     SELECT T_Id,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TCC_id) as rowno into #temp   
     FROM TCC WHERE CC_Id = @sourceCC
   select @total=COUNT(*) from #temp
   while(@rowno <> @total)
   begin
       Declare @t_id int
       set @t_id=(select top 1 T_id from #temp where rowno=@rowno)

       INSERT INTO TCC (TCC_Id, T_Id, CCC_Id) 
        VALUES (@sequence_id,@t_id,@targetCC)

       set @rowno=@rowno+1
   End
DROP TABLE #temp
CLOSE cursorCurrent
   DEALLOCATE cursorCurrent
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END
```